# Probability coupon collection question - nth coupon is a new type?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm just solving some probability problems in preparation for my exam, and I stumbled upon this one which I cannot tackle:

Suppose that you continually collect coupons and
that there are $m$ different types. Suppose also that
each time a new coupon is obtained, it is a type
$i$ coupon with probability $p_i, i = 1, \ldots ,m$. Suppose
that you have just collected your $n$-th coupon. What
is the probability that it is a new type? 
Hint: Condition on the type of this coupon.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple answer when the types of coupon have different probabilities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $E_n$ be the event of interest (at the $n$-th extraction we get a new coupon type) and let $c_n=1 \cdots m$ be the type of the $n-$th coupon. Then

$$P(E_n) =\sum_{i=1}^m P(E_n | c_n=i) P(c_n=i) = \sum_{i=1}^m (1-p_i)^{n-1} p_i$$

Comment: yup got it now, thank you

Comment: @leonbloy May you expand why P(E(n)/i)=(1-pi)^(n-1)? Thank you so much!

Comment: @leonbloy Is this the answer to my question? There are n-1 previous events, each one with probability 1-pi.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure, but is it this?
$$\sum_i p_i(1-p_i)^{n-1}$$

Comment: i am not sure either

Comment: You might try a simulation and see whether the probabilities work out.

Comment: yours is correct as well - summation to m to be more specific